# Why can't my project locate org.springframework.test or org.springframework.boot.test?

Tags: java, spring, gradle

**Problem:**

```
Error:(15, 10) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringRunner
Error:(16, 2) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol: class SpringBootTest
Error:(12, 47) java: package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
Error:(10, 47) java: package org.springframework.test.context.junit4 does not exist
/home/ian/Development/JavaEE/RestCalculator/src/main/java/com/testApp/calculator/ApplicationTest.java
Error:(11, 45) java: package org.springframework.boot.test.context does not exist
```

**Background**

I am trying to write a Unit test for a simple spring application. The application is built using Gradle. The following code is my build.gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

jar {
    baseName = 'calculator'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.10.RELEASE")
    }
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    compile("org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:1.3.2.RELEASE")
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    compile('junit:junit:4.12')
}
```

Attached is an image showing showing all the libraries associated with this project, which I believe includes the necessary test libraries.

[image]

**Question**

Why can't my project locate org.springframework.test or org.springframework.boot.test?

**Attempts at solution**

- I have run gradle clean, followed by a build
- I have updated the maven central repository
- I tried to force the version of org.springframework:spring-* to a higher version (5.0.3.Release)
- I tried using gradle-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE

I figure I must be missing something in my build.gradle, but I am at my wits end as to what it is. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have copy your gradle config, and everything seems working as expected,  to avoid any issue about starting new project you can download this [example](https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/) from spring guide and then customize dependencies as you like

Comment: Thanks @elmehdi it tried recreating my project as is and copying the gradle file from the spring documentation. Same error. When I followed the tutorial step by step I realized my mistake. I did not have a src/test/ directory.